# How to use list values globally in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I want to use the below `list` globally in my aspx page whose name is `lstUMSGroupDetails`. Currently I am getting its value from a function.

I want to use that list values in other functions too. SO how should I make it global.

its code is below

```
private void Get_AuthenticateUser_Ums(string strUName)
    {
        string strCurrentGroupName = "";
        int intCurrentGroupID = 0;
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strUName))
            {
                List<IPColoBilling.App_Code.UMS.UMSGroupDetails> lstUMSGroupDetails = null;
                List<IPColoBilling.App_Code.UMS.UMSLocationDetails> lstUMSLocationDetails = null;                   
                objGetUMS.GetUMSGroups(strUserName, out strCurrentGroupName, out intCurrentGroupID, out lstUMSLocationDetails, out lstUMSGroupDetails);

                if (strCurrentGroupName != "" && intCurrentGroupID != 0)
                {   
                    strCurrentGrp = strCurrentGroupName;                        
                    intCurrentGrpId = intCurrentGroupID;                       

                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Redirect("~/NotAuthorize.aspx", false);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string strErrorMsg = ex.Message.ToString() + " " + "StackTrace :" + ex.StackTrace.ToString();
            CommonDB.WriteLog("ERROR:" + strErrorMsg, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IPCOLO_LOG"].ToString());
        }
```

Comment: By 'Global', do you mean same for all users or same for a user-session?

Comment: @RahulSalvi: I mean to say here as for a `user session`

Comment: @BNN that's not "globally". User session data should be stored in the `Session` dictionary

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can store it in `Session`.

```
Session["lstUMSGroupDetails"] = lstUMSGroupDetails;
```

Then you can get this by.

```
List<IPColoBilling.App_Code.UMS.UMSGroupDetails> lstUMSGroupDetails = (List<IPColoBilling.App_Code.UMS.UMSGroupDetails>)Session["lstUMSGroupDetails"];
```

For more information please see [MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx).

Comment: thanks for ur answer mate, is there any other way than using session ??

Comment: Yes, You can make it public static and define it in global.

Comment: But session is best becuase every user will have its own list. Not common one.

Comment: @BNN `Session` is meant to store user session data, exactly what you asked for. Why are you looking for something else? Perhaps the real question you want to ask is different?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: No, I am satisfied with the above answer. and I am using it that only

Answer (score 1):

Could you not assign it to a slot in the Session Dictionary?

For example:

```
var myList = new List<int>();
Session["groups"] = myList;
```